# ASP.NET MVC 5.0 model class - how to have a property in model class but not create a Database field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This question is in regards to ASP.NET MVC 5.0 model class.

I have a ASP.NET MVC5.0 model class for example that looks like this

```
  public class Car
  {

        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string CarType { get; set; }

        public string SelectedType  { get; set; }

   }
```

However, I do not want a database field created for this model for property SelectedType.

Is there any attribute available to tell the Entity Framework not to create a database field for SelectedType?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I highly recommend against using your display models as your database entities.  The `Car` class should be owned by EF.  You should have a separate `CarModel` class for things like this.

Comment: Thanks I got that it is a good design to have separate classes for model and view model!! But I was wondering how to make EF not to create db fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `NotMapped` Data Annotation to exclude a purticular property like below:

```
public class Car
{
    //
    [NotMapped]
    public string  SelectedType  { set; get; }
}
```

You also can do this with `Fluent API`, but you need to override the `OnModelCreating` like below:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().Ignore(n => n.SelectedType   );
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use Fluent API ignore for example;

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().Ignore(t => t.Budget);
```